# How do I replicate Gmail's "to" field where each item is an indivisible span?

Tags: javascript, forms

I want to replicate the functionality of Gmail's "to" field where:

- Each address is actually a div or span containing information
- The user treats each email address as an atomic, indivisible element -- e.g. backspace will delete it with backspace
- Elements are added by autocomplete. The implementation of autocomplete is outside of scope of this question. It's only here to clarify that an element is not just "text".

Initially, I thought it should be a contenteditable element. However, inspecting Gmail's elements more closely, it looks to me like it's an element that just responds to keydown events

Is there an accepted, easy way to do this, other than implementing the element (as well as key navigation) by hand?

Comment: Show your current code and what you have tried, please.

Comment: That type of input is often called token input, and no there is no accepted standard implementation for it. I also needed such an input component a couple years ago, couldn't find anything suitable and ended up rolling my own. You can use it if you want, but it's old and depends on JQuery: http://tiguchi.github.io/tokchi/. I do not maintain that component anymore. Here's a mail app demo: http://tiguchi.github.io/tokchi/demo/email.html

Comment: I am trying to write a generic one. The answer here is helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `contenteditable` container, and disable the content-editability of inner, immutable elements:

```js
const input = document.querySelector("#input")
const button = document.querySelector("button")
button.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  input.innerHTML+='<span contenteditable="false"> Immutable string </span>'
})
```

```css
#input{
  border:1px solid black;
}
span[contenteditable="false"]{
  background-color:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="input" contenteditable="true"></div>
<button>Insert immutable test string</button>
```

Then, with some clever-written JavaScript, you can do anything with this approach.

Comment: I like this! Thanks for this